# ClassNotFoundException occurs in connectivity with MS SQL Server

Tags: jdbc

I have MS SQL Server 2008 database on server pc and I am trying to connect with that database from my local machine. On my local machine I have MS SQL Server 2012 and I have connected 2008 server database in my local pc. I have also added external jar file sqljdbc42.jar. When I run my java web application I get a ClassNotFoundException.

code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(Provider.CONNECTION_URL,Provider.USERNAME,Provider.PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connection........."+con);
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Statement...");
        String sql="select User_name,Password from tblBTUserMaster";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
         name1=rs.getString(4);
         password1=rs.getString(6);



Exception : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.LoginBean.validate(LoginBean.java:37)
    at com.ControllerServlet.doPost(ControllerServlet.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: _"I have also added external jar file sqljdbc42.jar"_ where did you add it? It is clearly not on the classpath of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add sqljdbc42.jar jar file in WEB-INF-->lib. just copy this jar file and paste in lib folder and then run it.